# How to encrypt variable size of data by using AES (CBC) 128 Algorithm

Tags: c, aes, caesar-cipher

I want encrypt 4 byte of data, but AES takes 16 byte of data as input and gives 16 bytes as output,
So How to overcome this problem, If some have source code please share

To encrypt 4 byte of data we need to add 12 more bytes and make a block of 16 bytes, its take more data length to transfer via wireless, So How to send Encrypted data with Real data length

Comment: Your chosen algorithm "AES-CBC" has a fixed block size of 16 bytes. That means it needs an input block that is 16 bytes long and produces an output block of 16 bytes (note: here I'm working with "NoPadding"). In short: the answer to your question "So How to send Encrypted data with Real data length" (when the data length is < 16) is "no way", sorry.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=aes-cbc+padding

Comment: @V  "How to send Encrypted data with Real data length" --> Is the data length _always_ a multiple of 8 bits (byte)? Or is the data length measured in bits?  Could the block have 0 bits/bytes of data?

Answer (score 1):

On encryption, append 12 bytes of random junk.
On decryption, ignore the last 12 bytes.

If length is not fixed, then
`[1-bit junk][7-bit bit-length][n-bits of data][128-8-n junk bits to fill to 128]`

Comment: Giving this more thought, I don't think this scheme is guaranteed to work in general. There's no way to tell in general if the input plaintext actually needed padding, and the max of 0x7F or 127 bits can't fit into the 15 bytes or 120 bits left in the final block. And if the input didn't need padding? There's no way to tell. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7: "If the length of the original data is an integer multiple of the block size B, then an extra block of bytes with value B is added. This is necessary so the deciphering algorithm can determine ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle True.  I posed some  questions for OP to get more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Cipher block chaining (CBC mode) requires that the plaintext be a mulitple of the block size.  If it is not, you'll need to pad it out to a multiple of the block size.

Cipher-feedback mode (CFB mode) exists primarily to avoid this -- as it uses the block cipher as a way of generating key bits to XOR with the the plaintext to encrypt it, it can be used with any bit length and padding is not needed.  With CFB mode, however, it is critical to not reuse IVs, as that will directly leak the first block of the plaintext.  In CBC mode, reusing IVs is still bad (will leak info about correlated inputs), but arguably not as bad.

Comment: Both AES-CTR and AES-GCM would also work without the need to pad the data, with the same, "Don't *ever* reuse the IV!" caveat.  But unless you're rolling your own, most implementations such as Java or OpenSSL will just do any padding needed for AES-CBC for you.